# cbook missing in fresh install of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6

I installed ipython and matplot lib via pip

when I try to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, I get this error:

```
bash-4.2$ ipython
Python 3.6.3 (default, Jan  4 2018, 16:40:53) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a0d2faabd9e9> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    125 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    126 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 127 from . import cbook
    128 from matplotlib.cbook import (
    129     _backports, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)

ImportError: cannot import name 'cbook'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Apparently something went wrong when installing or you installed something to a different location than the one you run it from. Such things usually happen if you have several python versions on your computer or installed non compatible versions of matplotlib and its dependencies. Really hard to tell with the information given.

Comment: I installed everything with --user. What info do you need?

Comment: How you installed it and to where. Also in how far those other questions with the same error are not helping here.

Comment: With pip, using the --user, i.e. to ~/.local

Comment: the other got solved by reinstalling or updating matplotlib, which doesn't apply, because my problem occurred on a fresh install